# Cut first x characters from a String in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell

I'm trying to create a function that concatenates parts of strings in a list to another. I already know how to select the strings I want but now I need the first part of them (and it's not always the same value).

So I want to cut the first part of a string

```
-- here is a function that should take a string and the numbers
-- of characters we want to take from the start
cutString :: Int -> String -> String
cutString x str = cut x str -- here's a way to take the first x characters
```

And the way to use it:

```
print (cutString 3 "Hello World")
Output --> "Hel"
```

Is there any simple ways to do that?

Thanks for any help or advices.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the number of characters is larger than the length of the string?

Comment: You are probably looking for [`take`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:take).

Comment: Haskell single-line comments are of the form `-- comment`, not `// comment`. I've edited your question to reflect that.

Comment: Lee in my case this should not happen, but I think it should return the entire string

Comment: When faced with such a question, consider using [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) rather than resorting to Stack Overflow. Hoogle can point you to existing functions whose signature (`Int -> String -> String`, here) is as desired. Then, scan the search results for a function that exhibits the desired semantics. [In this case](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int+-%3E+String+-%3E+String), `take` is the fourth result down the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [`take`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:take):

```hs
take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
```

> `take n`, applied to a list `xs`, returns the prefix of `xs` of length `n`, or `xs` itself if `n > length xs`

Using it in Prelude shows:

```hs
Prelude> take 3 "Hello"
"Hel"
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement `take` yourself with explicit recursion:

```
-- note the signature here is less general than it need be:
-- cutString :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
cutString :: Int -> String -> String
cutString 0 _      = []
cutString n (x:xs)
  | n > 0     = x : cutString (n-1) xs
  | otherwise = []
cutString _ _      = []
```

The first alternation is your usual base case -- taking zero elements of anything is the empty string: `[]`.

The second alternation is your recursive case. If n is zero, execution hits the first alternation, so we only have to worry about two cases here: either n is greater than zero in which case we give back one character and recurse with n-1, or n is less than zero in which case we catch the edge case and give back something sensible. Taking less than zero elements from a string isn't a sensible thing to do, so you could choose your response here -- `error` might be appropriate.

The third alternation is the fallback and is another base case. If `n` is still not zero, but we've run out of items in the string, stop recursing and give back `[]`. Without this case, the code crashes on `cutString 100 "Hello"` (anything where `n > length str`)